# Solve with a non-numerical-index constant

Tags: equation-solving, index, indexed-variable

I have 4 different constants in a given expression. Due to their physical interpretation, it makes sense to label them with non numerical indices, such as $r_+$.
The problem is that they prevent even simple commands from working, like `Solve[A (r - r_+)== B , r]` (imagine the "plus sign" as an index of the second "r").

Is there any elegant way out of this? I certainly cannot name my variable $r+$ and I would like to avoid large names (since my expressions are already too large).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just call it `rp`. You could also use `r₊` [(U+208A) subscript plus sign](https://unicode-table.com/en/208A/), but I recommend against that. Also `Subscript[r, "+"]`, but I don't like subscripts as they can cause problems - search for why.

Comment: Could also use `r["+"]`.

Comment: Dear Lichtblau, that does NOT qualify as an index, right? I guess that will solve my issue, in spite of not being so clean as an actual subscript.

Comment: If i use both suggestions I've received, i.e,  Format[r["+"]] = Subscript["r", "+"];
Solve[A (x - r["+"]) == B, r["+"]]

Then I'll get exactly what I was looking for:    $r_+= \frac{A x-B}{A}$.

Comment: However, it's not possible to calculate the derivative with a ('), since it will derive only the "r" in $r_+$, leaving a [["+"]]! The full command D[r-r[["+"]],r] works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to format output display of variables, e.g., `rm` and `rp`

```
Format[rm] = Subscript["r", "-"];
Format[rp] = Subscript["r", "+"];

Solve[A (r - rp) == B, r][[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Hanlon, if I use "Format" I'll have to use rm in every input formula and it's only the output that will show $r_+$, right?

Comment: Yes, `Format` only affects output display.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify how [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) works with subscripts:

```
Unprotect[Solve];
Solve /: Solve[a__] /; !FreeQ[{a}, _Subscript] := Block[{CompressedData},
    With[
        {z = Unevaluated[Solve[a]] /. s_Subscript :> CompressedData[Compress[s]]},
        z /; !MatchQ[z, _Solve]
    ]
]
Protect[Solve];
```

Then:

```
Solve[A (r - Subscript[r, "+"]) == B, r]
```

> {{r -> (B + A Subscript[r, "+"])/A}}

Another example:

```
Solve[1/r == 1/Subscript[r, 1] + 1/Subscript[r, 2], r] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\left\{r\to \frac{r_1 r_2}{r_1+r_2}\right\}\right\}$